# TFS 2013 edit,rollback issue

Tags: tfs

I have a question on TFS Server functionality. I took the latest version code from TFS Server and it shows that all files are up-to-date. But when I try to check-in my pending changes to TFS Server, some of the files are showing with edit & rollback, even though I never touched the files. The biggest trouble is the file showing latest status, but when I use compare filter it shows a lot of differences between the local file and the server file. Can anyone please explain to me, why it behaves like this?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes TFS gets confused and you have to do a Get Latest Version with the ["Overwrite writable files that are not checked out" and "Overwrite all files even if the local version matches the specified version" option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155787.aspx) options checked in order to get the actual latest versions.

Make sure you create a shelfset of your pending changes as a backup.